# Looking for a tool for creating complex UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibezierpath

Creating complex `UIBezierPath` is a hard work, almost impossible from what i have seen.

Let's say i want to create this:

[image: Example]

I know this can be done mathematically, but is there any known tool for creating such a path?

something that will translate the image to a path, even if it means i have to manually draw the path while the tool is "taking notes" and eventually will output my needed path?

I have tried this:[iPhone app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bezier-path-designer-draw/id598906638?mt=8)

But i can't set a background for reference.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a wonderful app called PaintCode.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Adobe Illustrator, you can use the drawscript plug in available at http://drawscri.pt/

Answer (score 1):

[Check out DrawKit](http://apptree.net/drawkitmain.htm)

[image]

> DrawKit attempts to do for drawing applications what Cocoa's text system does for text applications. It provides a set of interrelated classes which implement a complete vector-drawing framework, while trying to maximise flexibility and remaining agnostic about the final end use of the application. To this end, it provides:

- A fully abstracted "drawing" data model
- Unlimited drawing layers
- Any number of views can be simultaneously attached to view and edit the drawing
- A complete hierarchy of classes for vector drawing objects
- Specialised layers for grids, guides and drawing meta-data panels
- "Real-world" coordinates in millimetres, inches, kilometers or whatever you need
- A standardized selection mechanism and selection "knobs" just works, but easily customisable.
- Styles can be shared among objects or individually attached
- Classes for gradient fills, Bézier pattern fills, strokes and hatches
- Interactively editable Bézier paths of any complexity
- Draw bezier paths point-by-point or "freehand" with automatic smoothing
- Any image format supported by NSImage can be added as a standard object
- Convert any image to vector form†
- Editable text objects
- Text or any other shape or image on a path
- Add arrow heads to any path; automatic dimensioning lines for CAD-type applications
- Built-in snap to grid, snap to guides, align and distribute objects
- Group and Ungroup objects to any degree of nesting. Groups can be rotated and scaled like any object
- Rotate, Scale, Skew, Perspective and Free Distort transformations
- Union, Difference, Intersection and Exclusive-Or (Boolean Ops) on any pair of paths or shapes*
- Combine, Join or Break Apart arbitrary paths
- All object types can be freely interconverted
- A large array of built-in object path shapes which is simply extendible
- Simple tool-based drawing paradigm
- Core Image Effects may be applied to any object
- Undo handled for you
- Export any part of the drawing (or whole) as a PDF, JPEG, PNG or TIFF image
- All drawing ultimately performed by Quartz for spectacular quality
- Efficient object storage and drawing model for good performance

I'm not the author of it, but I *have* used it, and **i like it** (once I got it compiled, etc.)

Comment: Do you happen to know of a mirror/github/other home for this project? Looks like the download links there no longer work.